# Помогите разобраться со счетчиком на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, счетчики

Есть вот такой скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = [6,5,4,3,2,1,7];
    var today = new Date();
    var end = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()+ d[today.getDay()], 23, 59, 59);
    var sale = document.getElementsByClassName( 'sale' )[0];
    sale.innerHTML = 'акция до '+ end.toLocaleDateString();
</script>
```

Задача скрипта подставлять в

```
<div class="sale"></div>
```

текст "акция до такой-то даты". В качестве "такой-то даты" принимается ближайшая суббота и при ее достижения счетчик сбрасывается на следующую субботу. Примерно так.

Я в JS абсолютный 0, скрипт взят кусками из интернета и скорее всего он абсолютно корявый. Есть 2 проблемы: 1) текст подставляется только в первый div, хотя по коду страницы их много с классом sale. Прочитал, что getElementsByClassName возвращает массив и его нужно обработать через forEach, но вообще не понял как это сделать. 2) дата выводится в виде "12.02.2019", а нужно в виде "12 февраля". Помогите разобраться :)

Answer (score 0):

С первым пунктом разобрался сам, вот решение, может кому пригодится:

```
var d = [6,5,4,3,2,1,7];
var today = new Date();
var end = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()+ d[today.getDay()], 23, 59, 59);

var auc = document.getElementsByClassName('sale');
for (var i = 0; i < auc.length; i++) {
    auc[i].innerHTML = 'акция до '+ end.toLocaleDateString();
}
```

Помогите разобраться со вторым пунктом

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо мне, я разобрался и со вторым пунктом:

```
    var d = [6,5,4,3,2,1,7];
    var today = new Date();
    var end = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()+ d[today.getDay()], 23, 59, 59).toLocaleDateString('ru-RU', {
    day : 'numeric',
    month : 'long',
});

    var auc = document.getElementsByClassName('sale');
    for (var i = 0; i < auc.length; i++) {
        auc[i].innerHTML = 'акция до '+ end;
    }
```